# How do I instal wxPython 3 into my Conda Python 2?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, wxpython, conda

wxPython 3.0 is not available from pip; They say download it from Sourceforge. The installer from Sourceforge, however, fails with a meaningless error message:
[image]

I have tried `brew install wxpython`, and it installs fine, but Conda Python doesn't pick it up and continues to use the latest version (4) installed via pip.

What can I do?

Comment: wxPython 3 is pretty old. Do you have a reason for needing it instead of the latest?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll Yes, some app I need uses that.

Comment: I know when I installed 2.8 on my Mac, I had to change permissions for downloaded executables. I wonder if you need to do something like that for conda too?

Comment: Did you try some of the wxPython 3 versions on Anaconda Cloud? Here's one that sounds promising - https://anaconda.org/bjornfjohansson/wxpython

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I installed it now, but somehow Python is still using the newer version. Is there a path thing for Python packages?

Comment: Yes there is, it's `conda`. Did you install it into a new conda env in which you specified `python=2.7`?

Comment: @nekomatic No, I installed it into a Python 2.7 env I had from before. I'll try a new env, thanks.

Comment: OK... when you say *Python is still using the newer version*, which Python? Are you using it in an IDE and if so how have you ensured it's using the Python interpreter from the right env?

Comment: @nekomatic Thank you ❤️ It works! Though I needed to use `conda install python.app` and then use `pythonw` to finally run that app. This makes me think Python is bad for end-users? How can a normal user jump through this many non-trivial hoops to get a simple app running? Do most commercial Python apps just ship with a bundled virtual environment?

Comment: It's not my field of expertise but as I understand it if you want to deploy your app to end users you would use a tool like [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to create a standalone executable which installs like any other program, and the user doesn't need to even know that Python is involved.

Comment: Yes, you would bundle it up with PyInstaller or one of the many other executable building tools for Python

Answer (score 0):

The solution which I found thanks to Mike Driscoll and nekomatic:

1. Create a new conda env with Python 2.7.
2. Install https://anaconda.org/bjornfjohansson/wxpython .
3. `conda install python.app`
4. Use `pythonw` instead of `python`.

The last two steps are probably specific to macOS.